# Young Adult Science Fiction - Cord and Lamprey main character names

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book series I started but never finished 20+ years ago.  It was about a group of colonists who ended up on an inhabited planet.  Some, maybe all, of the characters were sent there as punishment for crimes.  The main character's name was Cord, he was really strong.  The villain's name was Lamprey, he was violent and had been in some kind of special ops military group back on Earth.

The native inhabitants of the planet were peaceful and not particularly dangerous, if I recall correctly.

Looking for this on Google has taught me much I didn't know about the spinal cords of lampreys and other fish, but no luck finding the book I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[Exiles of ColSec](http://www.pornokitsch.com/2012/01/underground-reading-exiles-of-colsec-by-douglas-hill.html)" by Douglas Hill. The main characters are:

- "**Cord MaKiy** ("teen protagonist and Scottish hillbilly")
- **The Lamprey** ("He's a former Civil Defender/Special Forces type")

[image]

Comment: For the record, I found this by googling ("Cord" + "lamprey" + "planet" + "Science Fiction"). Quotes are an excellent way to prevent google from being too helpful.

Comment: Nailed it, thank you!

Comment: I remember this :-) self-recharging weapons with a fusion power source called "sun guns".

Comment: Just to add that this was the first in a trilogy, with 'The Caves of Klydor' and 'Colsec Rebellion' being the other two books. I remember these being really good, and well worth a read at any age, even though they were published as young adult books.